# Spaces between control on xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use the following code to create a xamarin form using visual studio for android when i look into the output lot of spaces between the controls.

Attachment contains output in emulator. Please let me know how to reduce the space between the controls:

[image].

Code use to create a form:

Comment: Please paste the code to create the form

Comment: i cannot able to add the entire code

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5269250/Spaces-between-control-on-xamarin

check this for code

Answer (score 0):

You can add the specific value for your `Height` in `Grid`.(If you do not set it, the default value of the RowDefinition.Height property is *). If you do not want to set the specific `Height`, please change the value of `VerticalOptions` from `CenterAndExpand` to `Center`(Row 1 and Row 3's `Lable`).

Here is code.

```
    <ContentPage Title="Home" >
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid  ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                        <CarouselView x:Name="Imageslider">
                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="MonkeyFace.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CarouselView>
                    </Grid>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" Text="About Us" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Padding="2,0,2,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Text="Surabi Institute of Hotel Management and Fashion Technology recognized by Bharathidhasan University. Surabi Institute of Hotel Management and Fashion Technology was established in the year of 2006. The aim of the Founder is to Provide Hotel Management / Fashion Technology to the poor and Need of the Society">
                    </Label>
                    <!-- Place new controls here -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="3"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" Text="Saravana Educational  Welfare Trust" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]